# Sum to $n$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

If I have a general term of any series as $T_{n}=9n^2+12n+4$, then I can easily find the sum of this series upto $n$ terms by using some standard results as:

$$S_{n}=\frac{3n(n+1)(2n+1)}{2}+6n(n+1)+4n$$

> If I have a series whose general term is of this type $T_{n}=2^{n}-1$, then how do I find out the sum of this series upto $n$ terms?

Comment: It's basically the sum of a geometric progression.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n T_k = \sum_{k=0}^n 2^k - (n+1)
$$
and the left-hand term is now a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: @Tanuj $$\sum_{k=1}^n a^k = \frac{1 - a^{n+1}}{1-a}$$

Comment: Shouldn't the limit of $k$ be from $0$ to $n$?

Comment: @Tanuj yes it should, my bad

Comment: That's okay but I still don't get the point! Why does it have to from 0? What are we doing here exactly? Shouldn't the sum be taken from the first term, i.e. $k=1$?

Comment: @Tanuj no. We are saying that
$$
1 + a + a^2 + \ldots + a^n= \sum_{k=0}^n a^k = \frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}
$$